# ssh: connect to host 192.168.57.1 port 22: Connection refused lost connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables

I have two linux server running one having static IP(192.168.56.1) other with a static IP(192.168.57.1). I am able to ping both the servers with there static IP but when I tried to move a txt file from one machine to other

```
scp /home/sample.txt root@192.168.57.1:/home
```

I got an error `ssh: connect to host 192.168.57.1 port 22: Connection refused lost connection`I tried all the things like

```
sudo apt-get purge ssh-server
sudo apt-get install ssh-server ssh-client
```

and iptables but the problem still persist

Output after running `ssh 192.168.56.1 -vvv`:

[image: output after running ssh 192.168.56.1 -vvv]

Comment: Is the ssh port (22) open into the firewall? Through Iptables: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`; or through UFW: `sudo ufw allow ssh` or `sudo ufw limit ssh`.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the output of: `ssh 192.168.56.1 -vvv` (Verbose mode.). I think, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, when this error happens, it means that the SSH client can not establish a successful connection to the SSH server because *something* refused the connection's ability to exist.

Be sure any firewalls on your computers allow communication both in and out on port 22. If you're using `ufw`, this command is simply `ufw allow 22`.

Furthermore, it may be possible that your SSH server is not running. Try to run this command on the server:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Be sure to pay attention to any errors or the like that are returned (if any).

Also, check your SSH config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure that the server is actually listening on port 22 and is bound to allow connections. If these are not the case, change the settings appropriately and save the edited file. Restart the SSH server with the command given above.

Comment: I did both the things i.e ufw allow 22 and the sshd_config file shows the port 22 as the listening port still the problem persists